# If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}e_n x^n = 0$ always implies $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}e_n a_n = 0$, then $(a_n) = (x^n)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, golden-ratio

Let $x \in \left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}+1}, 1\right)$ and assume the real sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies

1. $a_1 = x,$
2. For every sequence $(e_n) \subset \left\{-1, 0, 1 \right\}$ with $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}e_n x^n = 0$ we have $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}e_n a_n = 0.$

**How can I show that this implies $(a_n) = (x^n)$?**

I can see why it's necessary to restrict the interval from which $x$ can be taken (For large/small enough $x$ the only way to get $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}e_n x^n = 0$ is to have $e_n = 0$ for all $n$), but I have no idea how to show the implication to be true in the given interval.

As $\frac1x$ has to be between $1$ and $\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$, there must be some connection to the golden ratio, but I don't see it yet.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: [A proof was posted on AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u1001617h1301612p26625214) a couple of months after I asked this question here.

Comment: If $x$ is a root of a polynomial with coefficients in $\{-1,0,1\}$ then we can use some linear algebra to finish? Say $p_nx^n+\cdots+p_0=0$ then set $a_{j+k}=p_j$ and $a_t=0\forall t\ge n+k$ or $t<k$ implies $a_n\equiv x^n$? Can we use continuity? This doesn't use $\frac 1x$ is in 1 and golden ratio though.

Comment: @KaiWang Do you mean setting $e_j$ to something? Because we can't choose the values of $(a_n)$...also I don't see how you're concluding $a_n = x^n$ from that. How would we use continuity here, continuity of what?

Comment: Updated my answer. See if it has anything useful for you.

Comment: Do we assume that $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent ?

Comment: we dont. I prove it.

Comment: @Cactus No, we don't.

Comment: I posted a follow up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4730902/which-x-in-mathbb-r-satisfy-a-property-related-to-sequences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A proof of this was posted in an AoPS forum a couple of months after I asked this question, but I forgot to update this thread. The idea was the following:

- For any $x \in \left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}+1}, 1\right)$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the sequence
  $$
  y_k^{(n)} :=\begin{cases}
  x^k, k<n\\
  x^{k+1}, k \geq n
  \end{cases}
  $$
  has the property that
  $$
  y_k^{(n)} \leq \sum_\limits{i\geq k+1}y_i^{(n)}
  $$
  for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
- This property guarantees that for any $y \in \left[0, \sum_\limits{k \in \mathbb{N}}y_k^{(n)}\right]$ we can find a set $M \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that
  $$
  \sum_\limits{k \in M}y_k^{(n)} = y.
  $$
- Given a nonempty set $A \subsetneq \mathbb{N}$ we can find nonempty sets $B \subset A, C \subset A^c$ such that
  $$
  \sum_\limits{k \in B}x^k = \sum_\limits{k \in C}x^k.
  $$
  This can be done the following way: Choose $n \in A$ such that
  $$
  \sum_\limits{k \in A}x^k \leq \sum_\limits{k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{n\}}x^k = \sum_\limits{k \in \mathbb{N}}y_k^{(n)},
  $$
  then from the previous point we get a set $M \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that
  $$
  \sum_\limits{k \in M}y_k^{(n)} = \sum_\limits{k \in A}x^k
  $$
  and therefore a set $M' \subset \mathbb{N}\setminus\{n\}$ such that
  $$
  \sum_\limits{k \in M'}x^k = \sum_\limits{k \in A}x^k.
  $$
  Thus we can choose $B := A \setminus M'$ and $C := M' \setminus A$.
- Now back to the original problem, let $x$ and $(a_k)$ be as stated in the question and assume towards a contradiction that $(a_k) \neq (x^k)$. For any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we can verify directly that the sequence $b_k := a_k + tx^k$ also satisfies condition $2$ from the question. Let us choose $t$ such that $A := \{k \in \mathbb{N}|b_k > 0\}$ is a nonempty proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$. From the previous point we get nonempty sets $B \subset A, C \subset A^c$ such that
  $$
  \sum_\limits{k \in B}x^k = \sum_\limits{k \in C}x^k,
  $$
  so if we set
  $$
  e_k := \chi_B(k) - \chi_C(k)
  $$
  for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, we get a sequence $(e_k) \subset \{-1, 0, 1\}$ satisfying
  $$
  \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}}e_k x^k = \sum_\limits{k \in B}x^k - \sum_\limits{k \in C}x^k = 0,
  $$
  but also
  $$
  \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{N}}e_k b_k = \sum_\limits{k \in B}b_k - \sum_\limits{k \in C}b_k > 0,
  $$
  contradicting the fact that $(b_k)$ also satisfies condition $2$.

Comment: +1 for your answer. First property which is the pivotal part of the answer is quite interesting. Cool property !

Comment: Please add the AoPS link to the body of the question ;]

Comment: @metamorphy done

Answer (score 0):

To put in some perspective, i have mentioned some basics. See if this is useful. The given problem is more specific than the general problem i treated below.

Property $P_N$:
$$E_N: = span \left(\{(e_n : n \leq N):, e_n \in \{-1,0,+1\}, \sum_{n\leq N} e_n x^n = 0\}\right)$$ $$ = W_N: = \{(w_n : n \leq N): (w_n: n \leq N) \in \ell_{\infty}(\mathbb{R}), \sum_{n \leq N} w_{n} x^n = 0\}$$

Then $$(a_n : n \leq N) = (x^n : n \leq N)$$

Note that $E_N \subseteq E_{N+1}$ and $W_N \subseteq W_{N+1}$ and $ E_N \subseteq W_N$.

If Property $P_N$ is not true for any $N$, then if $Closure(E_{\infty}) = W_{\infty}$, then,

$$\left\{(w_n): (w_n) \in \ell_{\infty}(\mathbb{R}), \sum_{n \geq 1} w_{n} x^n = 0 \right \} = \left \{(w_n): (w_n) \in \ell_{\infty}(\mathbb{R}), \sum_{n \geq 1} w_{n} a_n = 0 \right \}$$

Then $(x^n) \in \ell_1(\mathbb{R})$ is a linear functional with same kernel as $(a_n)$. Hence if $(a_n) \in \ell_1(\mathbb{R})$ then $(x^n) = (a_n)$.

We can choose $w_n = e_n = e_n^* =  sign(a_n)$ and hence $\sum_n |a_n| < \infty$.

If $\sum_n |a_n| = \sum_n e^*_n a_n = \infty$ then choose $e_n^{**} = sign(a_1) \delta(n-1)$ i.e., 1 for the first element and rest are zero.

Hence for some $\alpha < \infty$, $$\sum_n (\alpha e_n^* + e_n^{**}) x^n = 0 \implies \sum_n (\alpha e_n^* + e_n^{**}) a_n = 0 = (\alpha+1)|a_1| + \sum_{n \geq 2} |a_n| = 0 $$
Hence,
$$\sum_n |a_n| < \infty$$

Hence $(x^n) = (a_n) \iff  Closure(E_{\infty}) = W_{\infty}$.

The other way in the $\iff$ part comes from Hahn-Banach Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem

Proving $Closure(E_{\infty}) = W_{\infty}$ seems far fetched for now and does not seems to true. Not sure. This is exactly i think you need to prove.

Further Analysis:

Let $(e_n:n \neq N) \in E_N$ then,
$$\sum_{n \leq N} e_n x^n = 0 \implies $$
$x$ is a root of a polynomial with invariate $y$, $$f(y) = \sum_{n \leq N} e_n y^n = 0$$

Hence Wlog, $$f(y) = (y-x)(\sum_{n = 1}^{N-1} b_n y^n + e_0 x^{-1}) = \sum_{n \leq N} e_n y^n$$

Hence we get $$b_{n-2} - x b_{n-1} = e_{n-1}$$

We know that $$b_{0} = e_{0} x^{-1} \implies b_{0} - x b_{1} = e_{1} \implies b_{1} = x^{-1}(e_{0}x^{-1} - e_{1})  = x^{-2} e_0 - x^{-1} e_1 \implies b_1 -x b_2 = e_2 \implies b_2 = x^{-3}e_0  - x^{-2} e_1 - x^{-1} e_2$$.

Hence we have, $$b_n = e_0 x^{-n-1} - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} e_{n-j} x^{-j-1}$$

Hence $$E_N \ \tilde{=} \  R_{N-1} = span \left \{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b_n y^n: b_n = e_0 x^{-n-1} -  \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} e_{n-j} x^{-j-1}, e_j \in \{-1,0,+1\} \right \}$$

We also have that $$W_N \tilde{=} P_{N-1} = \left \{ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b_n y^n: b_n \in \mathbb{R} \right \}$$

So the question is whether $$R_{N-1} = P_{N-1}$$.

This is a reduction in problem since $P_{N-1}$ is the space of all polynomials of degree $\leq N-1$.

See if this reduction helps in proving $E_N = W_N$ or $E_N \neq W_N$ for every $N$.

Its already clear that $E_2 \neq W_2.$

You can extend the argument for condition on  $$Closure(E_{\infty}) = W_{\infty}$$ to be equivalent to $$Closure(R_{\infty}) = P_{\infty}.$$
where
$$R_{\infty} := span \left \{ \sum_{n \geq 0} b_n y^n :  b_{n} - x b_{n+1} = e_{n+1} \right\} = span \left \{ \sum_{n \geq 0} b_n y^n : b_n = e_0 x^{-n-1} - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} e_{n-j} x^{-j-1} \right\}$$
$$P_{\infty} := \left \{ \sum_{n \geq 0} b_n y^n : ROC = \{y \in (-1,1)\} \right\} $$
where $y$ is an invariate.
This is a reduction since now we have $P_{\infty}$ as the set of all analytic functions in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Isn't the closure of the span of sequences $(e_n) \subseteq \{ \pm 1, 0 \}$ the whole $l^\infty(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: We need to consider only sequences such that $\sum_n e_n x^n = 0$ and see if that spans sequences in $P_{\infty}$.

Comment: I don't understand why $W_N$ would be included in $W_{N + 1}$. You can find seqences $(w_n)$ such that $\sum_{n \geqslant N} w_nx^n = 0$ but $w_{N + 1} \neq 0$ and in this case, $\sum_{n \geqslant N + 1} w_nx^n \neq 0$.

Comment: I dont assume $w_{N+1} \neq 0$, $W_N$  are finite length sequences. I will correct it.

Comment: Yes, but it is possible. For example, the sequence $(0,1,0,0,\ldots)$ belongs to $W_0$ but not to $W_1$.

Comment: I am only saying a subset and not equal $W_0 \subseteq W_1$. extend it by $0$ and not $1$

Comment: Moreover, you don't use $x\geqslant(\sqrt5-1)/2$ anywhere. Are you trying to "prove" the claim with this condition dropped?

Comment: $x$ is a real number and hence will be a root of a polynomial we can construct and hence $W_N$ is a hyperplane and $W_N \neq 0$.

Comment: I have yet to complete the proof. I just made progress.

Comment: $(a_n) = (x^n) \iff E_N = W_N$ i.e., null space of $(x^n : n \leq N)$ is uniquely specified by $E_N$ and hence $(a_n)$ has to be scaled version of $(x^n)$

Comment: Ok, so in other words, you only consider sequences $(w_n)$ with $w_n = 0$ when $n > N$ in $W_N$ and $E_N$, right ? In this case, I agree that $W_N \subset W_{N + 1}$ and $E_N \subset E_{N + 1}$, but I doubt it is useful. Indeed, if $x$ is transcendental, then $E_N = \{0\}$ for all $N$.

Comment: If you find finite $N$ not useful, then take a look at $N = \infty$ case i have considered.